# Returning reordered array

Tags: java, arrays

I am taking in user input as "Email Phone Address" and want to return an array with the same info but reordered "Phone Address Email"

```
import java.util.*;

public class Info {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        String persInfo;
        System.out.print("Enter your email phone address: ");

        persInfo = userInput.nextLine();

        getInfo(persInfo);

    }

    public static String[] getInfo(String persInfo) {
        String[] allInfo = persInfo.split(" ");
        String email = allInfo[0];
        String phone = allInfo[1];
        String address = allInfo[2];

        String[] orderedInfo = new String[allInfo.length];
        orderedInfo[0] = allInfo[1];
        orderedInfo[1] = allInfo[2];
        orderedInfo[2] = allInfo[0];

        return orderedInfo;
    }

}
```

I thought the above might work, but when I do a test print, I get null contents for orderedInfo array. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: split by space(" ").. did you try it?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html: try something at least.

Comment: are you only ever going to have 3 elements you have to re-order?

Comment: I tried copying contents from first array into second array in a different order, but it's not quite working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getInfo(...)` returns an array, but you are not storing the result:

`final String[] info = getInfo(persInfo);`

Also, change your split to be `" "`, not `""`.